# Is there any way to insert a (hex) number in windows console instead of a character?

Tags: c, scanf

Like in the title. For example for a function:

```
scanf("%s",buf);
```

I would like instead of typing "name" insert something like: "\0x6E\0x61\0x6D\0x65", basically still just input characters, but as numbers. Obviously I can't change either the retrieving function and the format. I know it's not very likely to be possible and sorry for the question, but I would just like to make myself sure it's not. Thanks for any answers.

Comment: Well yes there is "any way". You have to parse the string yourself, though.

Comment: "Obviously I can't change either the retrieving function and the format." That doesn't seem very obvious, and this isn't even a programming question if you cannot change the code.

Comment: @Ed Heal to be able to insert any character 0-127

Comment: @user2031070 - This question has no context. Besides why are you using `scanf` to read binary data?

Comment: Are you typing "\0x6E\0x61\0x6D\0x65" as a string in the console? Or is the input a set of ASCII characters coming from another program which is being piped to your current question? In the first case, you can just use `scanf("%x%x%x%x", a,b,c,d)` and in the second case, you can use `getchar()` I think.

Comment: @Ed Heal, ssm It's not my app and yes, the app is meant to be buffer overflowed, believe it or not it is for learning purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean via the keyboard, then yes, that's possible, but only as decimal codes. Hold down the `Alt` key while pressing the number of the desired character on the numeric key pad and then release the `Alt` key.